# Using react-testing-library to test that api call was made (which uses react-query)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-query

I have a component called LoggedIn.js, which uses react-query's `useQuery` hook to make an api call to my server upon LoggedIn.js loading:

```
    const {
    data,
    isSuccess,
    isFetching,
    isError,
    error,
    refetch: refetchAllRecipes
    } = useQuery(['getRecipes', userId], () => getRecipes(userId), {
            staleTime: Infinity,
            cacheTime: Infinity,
            refetchInterval: 0,
            refetchOnMount: true,
            refetchOnWindowFocus: false
        });
```

where `getRecipes` is a function I wrote that exists in another file:

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_SERVER}/api/`,
    timeout: 30000
});

export async function getRecipe(userId, id) {
    try {
        const response = await api({
            method: 'get',
            url: `users/${userId}/recipes/${id}`,
            withCredentials: true
        });

        return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err.response.data;
    }
}
```

I am trying to test that `getRecipes` is called when LoggedIn.js is mounted. Here is the relevant portion of the testing file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render, screen, act} from '@testing-library/react';
import {QueryClientProvider, QueryClient} from 'react-query';
import {ChakraProvider} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import * as RRD from 'react-router-dom';
import * as api from '../../../api/api';

import LoggedIn from '../LoggedIn';


const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const MockLoggedIn = (props) => {
    return (
        <QueryClientProvider
            client={queryClient}
            isLoggedIn={props.isLoggedIn}
        >
            <RRD.BrowserRouter isLoggedIn={props.isLoggedIn}>
                <ChakraProvider isLoggedIn={props.isLoggedIn}>
                    <LoggedIn isLoggedIn={props.isLoggedIn}/>
                </ChakraProvider>
            </RRD.BrowserRouter>
        </QueryClientProvider>
    );
};

    test('should make api call upon loading', async () => {
        const spy = jest.spyOn(api, 'getRecipes');

        act(() => {
            render(<MockLoggedIn isLoggedIn={true} />);
        });

        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

This test keeps failing, saying that `getRecipes` is never called. However, I know that it's called because if I put a console.log statement in `getRecipes`, then that message prints to the console. Obviously `spy`, in this case, is not properly spying on `getRecipes`. I'm stumped, because I am able to spy on other api calls that react-query makes for me - but I must say that those functions use `useMutation` rather than `useQuery`. This is my first time trying to test an api call that is being made using `useQuery`.

Some thoughts:

Technically, I do not pass `getRecipes` to the `useQuery` hook. I pass an anonymous function which calls `getRecipes`:

`useQuery(['getRecipes', userId], () => getRecipes(userId)...`

However, the problem persists even if I pass `getRecipes` directly and destructure the `queryKey` in my api call.

Also, if I put `console.log('hey')` in `getRecipes` (just to see if it was called) then this prints to the console:

```
console.log
    hey

      at Object.getRecipes [as queryFn] (src/api/api.js:195:11)
```

Notice the [as queryFn] part? It seems as if `getRecipes` isn't actually being called a react-query function is being called that somehow mimics `getRecipes`? Sounds weird. Not sure if I'm explaining thoughts properly here. I just figured that react-query would be calling `getRecipes`, but it looks like it isn't.

An obvious solution would be to just mock useQuery and test to see if that gets called. I've done that, and it indeed does get called **and** returns the correct data. However, this would be testing implementation rather than behaviour, so I would much rather test to see that `getRecipes` itself is called.

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the function name is `getRecipes`? But you declare the function with the name `getRecipe`. Besides, I can't reproduce your issue. Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this instead of using `act()`?

```js
render(<MockLoggedIn isLoggedIn={true} />);
await waitFor(() => expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled())
```

this is just a guess.

Could you provide some minimal reproduction repository?